# xdebug 2.5.1 not work on PHP version: 7.0.15-0 ubuntu0.16.04.4

Tags: php, xdebug

Below is my /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

```html
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so  
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back= on
xdebug.remote_autostart = on
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

[image]
[image]

**I cannot enable the xdebug.remote_enable why? And I cannot debug as normal. Anyone know what's problem with xdebug?**

```html
Xdebug installed: 2.5.1
Server API: Command Line Interface
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.0.15-0
Zend API nr: 320151012
PHP API nr: 20151012
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Configuration File: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php/20151012
```

---

Comment: Confirm you're editing the right ini file for what your IDE is using. Info should be towards the top of phpinfo.

Comment: Pretty sure anything else can be enabled/disabled except xdebug.remote_enable

Comment: "Pretty sure" doesn't really cut it. Test, confirm.

Comment: If I change other option, all OK. Only xdebug.remote_enable NOT work. The ini file is located: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

Comment: 1) Enable xdebug log and try to debug something -- see where it will try to connect and if it will try it at all. If nothing -- try adding `xdebug_break();` into your code (programmatic breakpoint) 2) Try disabling all extra extensions (leave bare minimum) -- any better?